# Convert CUDA tensor to NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

First of all, I tried those solutions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467215/convert-pytorch-tensor-to-numpy-array-using-cuda), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035617/how-to-convert-tensor-to-numpy-array), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931333/convert-tensor-to-numpy-array), and [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148590/convert-tensor-to-numpy-without-a-session), but did not work for me.

After training and testing the neural network, I am trying to show some examples to verify my work. I named the method **predict** which I pass the image to it to predict for which class it belongs:

```
def predict(model, image_path, topk=5):
''' Predict the class (or classes) of an image using a trained deep learning model.
'''

output = process_image(image_path)
output.unsqueeze_(0)
output = output.cuda().float()

model.eval()

with torch.no_grad():
    score = model(output)
    prob, idxs = torch.topk(score, topk)

    # Convert indices to classes
    idxs = np.array(idxs)
    idx_to_class = {val:key for key, val in model.class_to_idx.items()}
    classes = [idx_to_class[idx] for idx in idxs[0]]

    # Map the class name with collected topk classes
    names = []
    for cls in classes:
        names.append(cat_to_name[str(cls)])

    return prob, names
```

Then there is the final step which displays the final result based on the training of the neural network and done like this:

```
# TODO: Display an image along with the top 5 classes
x_pos, y_pos = predict(model, img_pil, topk=5)

ax_img = imshow(output)
ax_img.set_title(y_pos[0])

plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
plt.barh(range(len(y_pos)), np.exp(x_pos[0]))
plt.yticks(range(len(y_pos)), y_pos)

plt.show()
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-e3f9951e9804> in <module>()
----> 1 x_pos, y_pos = predict(model, img_pil, topk=5)
      2
      3 ax_img = imshow(output)
      4 ax_img.set_title(y_pos[0])
      5

1 frames
<ipython-input-44-d77500f31561> in predict(model, image_path, topk)
     14
     15         # Convert indices to classes
---> 16         idxs = np.array(idxs)
     17         idx_to_class = {val:key for key, val in model.class_to_idx.items()}
     18         classes = [idx_to_class[idx] for idx in idxs[0]]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    456     def __array__(self, dtype=None):
    457         if dtype is None:
--> 458             return self.numpy()
    459         else:
    460             return self.numpy().astype(dtype, copy=False)

TypeError: can't convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

**How do I solve this?**

I tried to change idx to `idxs = idxs.cpu().numpy()` and the error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-e3f9951e9804> in <module>()
      5
      6 plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
----> 7 plt.barh(range(len(y_pos)), np.exp(x_pos[0]))
      8 plt.yticks(range(len(y_pos)), y_pos)
      9

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    456     def __array__(self, dtype=None):
    457         if dtype is None:
--> 458             return self.numpy()
    459         else:
    460             return self.numpy().astype(dtype, copy=False)

TypeError: can't convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

Comment: you error log is not complete. you should copy your error log as text, not a figure

Comment: fixed it and removed the figure

Comment: are you sure you post all of the error log?

Comment: yes for sure, didn't miss anything

Comment: there may be some information collapsed?  what's `1 frames` ?

Comment: you were right there was missing lines and added now

Comment: Blind guess: what happens if you write `idxs = np.array(idxs.cpu())` (`.cpu()` being the new part)

Comment: still the same::  TypeError: can't convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change

```
idxs = np.array(idxs)
```

to

```
idxs = idxs.cpu().numpy()
```

And change

```
plt.barh(range(len(y_pos)), np.exp(x_pos[0]))
```

to

```
plt.barh(range(len(y_pos)), np.exp(x_pos[0].cpu().numpy()))
```

Comment: still the same error: TypeError: can't convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.

Comment: you first change to `idxs = idxs.cpu().numpy()` and show the complete error information. there may be somewhere else existing the same error

Comment: may be you can't change at your post.  I can't understand the comment as the disorder format.

Answer (score 3):

So if you're here in 2021 and still have this "***TypeError: can't convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.***"

Try `x.to("cpu").numpy()` from this site https://jbencook.com/pytorch-numpy-conversion/

So something like `idxs = idxs.to("cpu").numpy().squeeze()` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy does not use GPU; Numpy operations have to be done in CPU. Torch.Tensor can be done in GPU. So wherever numpy operations are there you need to move it to CPU

Ex `device` below is CPU; Model is run in GPU

```
    df["x"] = df["x"].apply(lambda x: torch.tensor(x).unsqueeze(0))
    df["y"] = df["x"].apply(lambda x: model(x.to(device))[0].detach())
```

and below when you need to use np.pad, you move it back to cpu

```
df["y"] = df["y"].apply(lambda x: np.pad(x.to("cpu"), [(0, 0), (0,  max_length - x.shape[1])], 'constant')  )
```